# How to show a modal window with text and img clicking on a thumbnail img

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I just started using Bootstrap 3. I made a thumbnail grid with images related to different projects. I would like that when clicking on an image a modal window open. In the modal I need to report image coming from thumbnail and some text explaining the project content.
Any idea, suggestion of how to do it?

Comment: Dont get me wrong You have to put some effort into it and do some work if you get stuck somwhere ask for solution for that part

Comment: Yes, I have lots of ideas and suggestions but I need to see some code, some effort and what you've tried so far and why you seem to think it's not working!

Answer (score 0):

Adding modals in Bootstrap is very easy, and there are examples in the Bootstrap documentation: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals.

I suggest trying out some of the examples and seeing how far you can get, and then if you get stuck you can ask for specifics.

Answer (score 0):

I' coding as follow

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-thumbnail"><a class="" href="#" title="Renovations"><img src="//placehold.it/600x400/444/F8F8F8" class="img-responsive"></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <p class="">Renovations</p>
                        <p class=""></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!--/panel-->
            </div>
            <!--/col-->
            <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-thumbnail"><a class="" href="#" title="Academic Institutions"><img src="//placehold.it/600x400/454545/FFF" class="img-responsive"></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <p class="">Academic Institutions</p>
                        <p class=""></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!--/panel-->
            </div>
            <!--/col-->
            <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-thumbnail"><a class="" href="#" title="Interiors"><img src="//placehold.it/600x400/555/F2F2F2" class="img-responsive"></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <p class="">Interiors</p>
                        <p class=""></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!--/panel-->
            </div>
            <!--/col-->
            <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-thumbnail"><a class="" href="#" title="New Construction"><img src="//placehold.it/600x400/555/FFF" class="img-responsive"></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <p class="">New Construction</p>
                        <p class=""></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!--/panel-->
            </div>
            <!--/col-->
            <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-thumbnail"><a class="" href="#" title="Site Planning"><img src="//placehold.it/600x400/555/EEE" class="img-responsive"></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <p class="">Site Planning</p>
                        <p class=""></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!--/panel-->
            </div>
            <!--/col-->
            <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-thumbnail"><a class="" href="#" title="Churches"><img src="//placehold.it/600x400/666/F4F4F4" class="img-responsive"></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <p class="">Churches</p>
                        <p class=""></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!--/panel-->
            </div>
            <!--/col-->
        </div>
        <!--/row-->
</div>
<!--/container-->
</pre>
```

and js script as follow

```
/* copy loaded thumbnails into carousel */
$('.panel .img-responsive').on('load', function() {

}).each(function(i) {
  if(this.complete) {
    var item = $('<div class="item"></div>');
    var itemDiv = $(this).parent('a');
    var title = $(this).parent('a').attr("title");

    item.attr("title",title);
    $(itemDiv.html()).appendTo(item);
    item.appendTo('#modalCarousel .carousel-inner'); 
    if (i==0){ // set first item active
     item.addClass('active');
    }
  }
});

/* activate the carousel */
$('#modalCarousel').carousel({interval:false});

/* change modal title when slide changes */
$('#modalCarousel').on('slid.bs.carousel', function () {
  $('.modal-title').html($(this).find('.active').attr("title"));
})

/* when clicking a thumbnail */
$('.panel-thumbnail>a').click(function(e){

    e.preventDefault();
    var idx = $(this).parents('.panel').parent().index();
    var id = parseInt(idx);

    $('#myModal').modal('show'); // show the modal
    $('#modalCarousel').carousel(id); // slide carousel to selected
    return false;
});
```

So I send image from thumbnail to a modal window with a carousel. What I would like is to add some text to each of the image displayed in the modal.
Thanks for some help.